# Android ListView divider strange problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a **ListView** with a **divider** of 1pd thickness. But somehow every second divider in the ListView is thicker then the others ...as you can see on the picture

[image]

the code of the ListView is real simple :

```
 <ListView 
         android:id="@+id/directoriesListView"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:layout_weight="2.5"
         android:cacheColorHint="@null"
         android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
         android:fadingEdge="none"
         style="@style/ListView_NarrowItems"
         />
```

and the style :

```
<style
    name="ListView_NarrowItems"
    >
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
</style>
```

any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android is scaling your activity. Add the appropriate `<supports-screens>` element to your manifest, set to indicate what screen sizes you are handling, and this effect should disappear.

Comment: Also, it might help using dp instead of px. On some devices lines which are only 1px will dissapear altogether.

Comment: Could you give me a hint what to set it to?

Comment: <supports-screens> element not worked for me... it still have creating this problem.... how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2011/03/30/android-list-view-alternating-between-1px-and-2px-dividers/comment-page-1/#comment-160763) blog post it's due to your application running in compatibility mode and the solution is to put minSdk and targetSdk in your application manifest like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```